# Problema: Al retornar un flux de tipo ResponseEntity

Tags: spring-boot, programación-funcional, flux, programación-reactiva

Yo tengo el siguiente fragmento de código que retorna un Flux de un ResponseEntity:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}") 
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Response>> findByDocumentClient(@PathVariable("id") String document){
return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(new Response(technomechanicalService.findByDocumentClient(document), HttpStatus.OK.value(), null), 
                        HttpStatus.OK))
        .onErrorResume(error -> {
            return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(new Response(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), error.getMessage()), 
                                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
        });
 }
```

El Metodo technomechanicalService.findByDocumentClient retorna un Flux.

El Objeto Response es el siguiente:

```
public class Response {

private Object body;
private Integer status;
private String descStatus;

public Response(Object body, Integer status, String descStatus) {
    this.body = body;
    this.status = status;
    this.descStatus = descStatus;
}

}
```

Cuando estoy consumiendo el método Get por postman, el servicio responde lo siguiente:

```
{ "body": { "scanAvailable": true, "prefetch": -1 }, "status": 200, "descStatus": null }
```

Porque genera esta respuesta? Porque no responde la lista de objetos?

Comment: Deberías de colocar el objeto que retorna findByDocumentClient para poder verificar la estructura.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran esta es la firma del servicio `Flux<TechnomechanicalEntity> findByDocumentClient(String document);`

Comment: Entonces  @JuanDavidBáezRamos debes de colocar en tu pregunt el codigo del la clase TechnomechanicalEntity.